# Network alias for Kubernetes ClusterIP Service

Tags: kubernetes, networking, service, docker-compose, alias

Is there a way for a Kubernetes ClusterIP Service to have a network alias, other than its `metadata.name` field value?

Docker-compose has a similar functionality with [network aliases](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#aliases).

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak currently using v1.19.7

Answer (score 2):

If I good understand your question you can also configure HostAliases for a Pod under `.spec.hostAliases` using `/etc/hosts` file. Look at the example:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hostaliases-pod
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  hostAliases:
  - ip: "127.0.0.1"
    hostnames:
    - "foo.local"
    - "bar.local"
  - ip: "10.1.2.3"
    hostnames:
    - "foo.remote"
    - "bar.remote"
  containers:
  - name: cat-hosts
    image: busybox
    command:
    - cat
    args:
    - "/etc/hosts"
```

> In addition to the default boilerplate, you can add additional entries to the `hosts` file. For example: to resolve `foo.local`, `bar.local` to `127.0.0.1` and `foo.remote`, `bar.remote` to `10.1.2.3`, you can configure HostAliases for a Pod under `.spec.hostAliases`.

You can find more information about Host Aliases [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/network/customize-hosts-file-for-pods/):

Comment: I understand, but i want the aliasing to take place in the Service level, not the Pod level.

Comment: As far as I know, there are therefore no options other than the one you gave and the one in my answer.